# Scraper collecting the content of first page only

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, return

I've written a scraper using python to scrape movie names  from yiffy torrents. The webpage has traversed around 12 pages. If i run my crawler using `print` statement, it gives me all the results from all the pages. However, when I run the same using `return` then it gives me the content from the first page only and do not go on to the next page to process the rest. As I'm having a hard time understanding the behavior of return statement, if somebody points out where I'm going wrong and give me a workaround I would be very happy. Thanks in advance.

This is what I'm trying with (the full code):

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urljoin
from lxml.html import fromstring            

main_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/western/"

# film_storage = [] #I tried like this as well (keeping the list storage outside the function)

def get_links(link):
    root = fromstring(requests.get(link).text)
    film_storage = []
    for item in root.cssselect(".mv"):
        name = item.cssselect("h3 a")[0].text
        film_storage.append(name)
    return film_storage

    next_page = root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')")[0].attrib['href'] if root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')") else ""
    if next_page:
        full_link = urljoin(link,next_page)
        get_links(full_link)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    items = get_links(main_link)
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

But, when i do like below, i get all the results (pasted gist portion only):

```
def get_links(link):
    root = fromstring(requests.get(link).text)
    for item in root.cssselect(".mv"):
        name = item.cssselect("h3 a")[0].text
        print(name)            ## using print i get all the results from all the pages

    next_page = root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')")[0].attrib['href'] if root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')") else ""
    if next_page:
        full_link = urljoin(link,next_page)
        get_links(full_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement prematurely terminates your get_links() function. Meaning this part

```
next_page = root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')")[0].attrib['href'] if root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')") else ""
    if next_page:
        full_link = urljoin(link,next_page)
        get_links(full_link)
```

is never executed.

Quickfix would be to put the return statement at the end of your function, but you have to make film_storage global(defined outside the get_links() function).

Edit:
Just realized, since you will be making your film_storage global, there is no need for the return statement.

Your code in main would just look like this:

```
get_links(main_link)
for item in film_storage:
    print(item)
```

Comment: This seems to be promising. Giving it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, this is just a quickfix solution as you mentioned that you are just beginning your scraping journey. But I suggest that you try @randomir's solution/suggestions in the future. That way, you can make better and more efficient scrapers.

Comment: Sorry, just realized, since film_storage is global, there is no need for the return statement.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Basically, what i have pasted here is a very small portion of my full code which should be reused by  a class. Thanks again.

Comment: Your suggested part for the main statement is working as well. Btw, what was wrong with the way I have written the portion under main statement? Please care to respond. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion in changing the main statement is due to the fact that film_storage is global. There is no need for a return statement since film_storage is accessible anywhere in your function. Your previous version (with return statement) is redundant since it just makes a copy of film_storage and saves it to a new variable. This makes your code inefficient in terms of memory and processing power especially if there are many links.

Comment: You are just awesome. Thanksssss a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your `film_storage` results list is **local to the function `get_links()`** which is called recursively for the next page. After the recursive call (for all the next pages), the initial (entry) function returns results only for the first page.

You'll have to either (1) unwrap the tail recursion into a loop, (2) make results list global; (3) use a callback (like you call `print`), or the best option (4) is to **turn the `get_links` function into a generator** that yields results for all pages.

Generator version:

```
def get_links(link):
    root = fromstring(requests.get(link).text)
    for item in root.cssselect(".mv"):
        name = item.cssselect("h3 a")[0].text
        yield name

    next_page = root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')")[0].attrib['href'] if root.cssselect(".pager a:contains('Next')") else ""
    if next_page:
        full_link = urljoin(link,next_page)
        for name in get_links(full_link):
            yield name
```

Comment: Thanks for the input randomir. +1 for this.

Comment: You're welcome, but please note you should really try to avoid global variables. They make your code less readable, **different parts of program are coupled in unexpected ways**, and overall your programs much more error prone.